# How many publications/citations/h-factor for EE tenure track in top ~100 research university?

Tags: publications, citations, tenure-track, early-career

Does anyone know of statistics how many publications/citations/h-factor an assistant professor in Electrical Engineering has at the beginning of tenure track in a top 100-200 research university?

If there are no statistics: What could be typical numbers? While I know that scoring a tenure track depends on a lot of things, I would be curious what the average and variance is and what would be a good number to set as a goal.

*Reason for my question:* I have a PhD from a top 3 university from a well known PI in the field. I did not really consider an academic career before and hence my publication record is (very) sub-optimal compared with other people I know. I have two journal papers, one conference and some patents (for some reason nobody seemed too interested in my work so I have only a few citations). I am planning for a postoc but since this is a big decision I want to be very clear what my goals should be.

Comment: It's a little bit specific.

Comment: # of publications and # of citations are so low at the time when people get hired into assistant professor positions that they are essentially meaningless. People get hired not for the papers they have written, but for the promise to write papers.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth This is somewhat hard to believe. The commitee must base their decision on something (and I know publications are not everything but I am very confident they play a big role). I edited my question to provide some background.

Comment: Electrical engineering is quite low comparing to other fields. What are of EE?

Comment: @mellin Yes, of course. But people applying for assistant professor positions typically have 5-10 papers, and they haven't been out long enough to garner a substantial number of citations -- so their H index is maybe 3-6. Of course people take into account number of publications when they look at candidates, but the *quality* of these papers matters a great deal more simply because for such low numbers, the numbers themselves are not so statistically meaningful if not put into context.

Comment: Depends on where you are.  In Australia, we have many people who have gone through multiple post-docs and posses a CV that is better than most academics, and yet they are still looking for a  job.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I think it really depends on the country, but also on your field. A comment that came up during some interviews for a tenure track position was that I had too few journal articles, while at that time I had something close to 15. Sometimes faculties have unrealistic expectations of just how much quality work you can publish. In my case the field was engineering-related.

Comment: @BlaB: Huh, how bizarre. Was this after just one 3-year postdoc? Regardless, I'm glad you got the job, we like you in our community :-)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth in my case this was after 2-3 years as a researcher in a national lab ( in which you generally publish less). Expectations are sometimes over the top. This emphasis on number of papers and citations is not very constructive. Actually, it is not even legal for our funding agency to use these type of metrics in Canada !